# SELECT statement gives fatal error: Invalid parameter number in

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, pdo

I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter
>   number in

this is my code (this does not work):

```
"SELECT id, username, email, password FROM users WHERE (username = :usernameOrEmail OR email = :usernameOrEmail) AND password = :password"
```

---

but if I remove the the `OR`, then it works!

```
"SELECT id, username, email, password FROM users WHERE username = :usernameOrEmail AND password = :password"
```

Comment: your first query also looks fine. But try once `"SELECT id, username, email, password FROM users WHERE password = :password AND (username = :usernameOrEmail OR email = :usernameOrEmail)"` and let us know worked or not. May be you have some error in the next line when you are assigning the values to `:usernameOrEmail`  and `:password`

Comment: You may have to bind `:usernameOrEmail` twice.  Just because you use the same parameter does not mean you won't need 3 bindings.

Comment: using prepare ?

Comment: You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name twice in a prepared statement :

Answer (score -1):

This is PHP version BUG
You tried update php version

Answer (score -2):

Try with the below query

```
SELECT 
    id, username, email, password 
FROM 
    users 
WHERE 
    :usernameOrEmail 
    IN (username,email) 
    AND password = :password
```

As you cannot use a named parameter marker more than one times in a query.